# How can i concatenate in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I'm new to javascript. how can i concatenate below variable

```
 var name = 'test';
 var query = /^ name / ;

db.users.find('name':query);
```

Expected output

```
query = /^ test/;
```

I want query without double quotes please some one help me to go move forward

I tried like this

```
var query ='/^' +'name'+ '/';
```

but i'm getting result with double quotes "/^ test/".

FYI : I don't want double quotes outside

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `db.users.find`?

Comment: try this ``var query =`'/^name/'`;``

Comment: @Jamiec as much I know `db.users.find` is nothing but mongodb query

Comment: find query for name. please disregard that.

Comment: well its relevant - as maybe there is a way to parameterize it with the library you're using. ie, are you attempting to "re-invent the wheel"? Basically, I think this is an XY Problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a variable in a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal.  I don't think the interpreter would understand that.  However, you can pass a *string* to the regular expression constructor, and strings can be concatenated/interpolated all you like.

For example:

```
var name = 'test';
var query = new RegExp('^ ' + name);
```

or:

```
var name = 'test';
var query = new RegExp(`^ ${name}`);
```

Comment: need one help . need like this /^ test/i .help me on this

Comment: @sportive: The `i` would be known as a "flag", and is an optional second argument to the `RegExp` constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp  So for example you may have something like: `new RegExp('^ test', 'i')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `/regex/g` syntax, you can construct a new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object:

```
var name = "test";
var re = new RegExp(name, "g");
```